# C: Ignore second definition of function if already defined

Tags: c, include, clang, llvm-clang

I have two files written in `C`, where the first file includes a different implementation of several functions that are already implemented in the second file. Is there any way to tell `clang` -- "If a function is already implemented in `File1`, then use that implementation instead of the `File2` implementation"? I understand that this is a terrible idea, fragile, obscure... but I was still wondering if the compiler is open to such mis-use/abuse?

Comment: You could probably use `#define` and `#ifndef` to do something like header guards do. `#define` a name during the first implementation, then check for its existence before allowing the second definition to run. Then include them in the priority order. How though would you not know if a definition exists in the first file?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the inferior function in a library and link with both the object file of the superior function and this library, the linker will ignore the inferior function.

### Edit:

This is "so1.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void) {
  puts("One.");
}
```

This is "so2.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void) {
  puts("2!");
}
```

This is "som.c" (the declaration of `f()` could have been in an extra header file):

```
void f(void);

int main(void) {
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

These are the command to check this out:

```
clang -c so1.c -o so1.o
clang -c so2.c -o so2.o
clang -c som.c -o som.o
ar r so1.lib so1.o
ar r so2.lib so2.o
clang so1.o   so2.o   som.o -o so12
clang so1.lib so2.o   som.o -o so_2
clang so1.o   so2.lib som.o -o so1_
so_2
so1_
```

The line `clang so1.o so2.o som.o -o so12` doesn't link and gives an error, as expected.

Both executables work as expected.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks!